# Why do different versions of Good Omens have such different page counts?

Tags: books, good-omens

I have the first Corgi paperback edition of *Good Omens*, which ran at 393 pages. Later editions, **even with the same ISBN**, have 412 pages: see [here](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28448121-good-omens). Why such a difference? I know that the first American edition has 700 words more than the Gollancz hardback edition, as reported in the [APF](http://www.au.lspace.org/books/apf/good-omens.html); but I thought that the paperback was prepared against the American edition...

Comment: Bigger text, probably

Comment: Later editions may have an author's forward, as well. Not sure if the first edition got that?

Comment: @Valorum: Normally, hardcovers, soft covers, and other variations are *supposed* to get separate ISBNs because they're not the same book. However, if they took an old edition and "reprinted" it in a slightly different format or pagination, I think they are allowed to reuse the ISBN. But you're supposed to assign [a new ISBN for a new edition](https://www.isbn.org/faqs_formats_reprints_editions).

Comment: Hmm.  [ISFDb](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?6543) lists the Corgi paperback as having 382 or 383 pages.  A little experimentation indicates that Corgi numbers from the first page of the front matter, with the story starting on p. 11 or 13.  ISFDb gives a page count based on the last page of the novel, discounting any following promotional material.  So the page count for a Corgi novel may differ from that of another publisher which numbers the front matter separately, even if the pages themselves are exactly the same.

Comment: (cont'd) Grabbing a couple of other books from other publishers, it appears that ISFDb's page count is simply the number of the last page of the story, irrespective of whether or not the front matter is included in the page numbering.  So if identical text is laid out exactly the same, but the page numbering includes the front matter in one case but not the other, then the nominal page count will differ.

Comment: (cont'd) Without access to the actual books, it's hard to speculate.  But again, even with identically laid out text, some publishers will start all chapters on a facing page, even if it means leaving a blank page.  That would also pad the page count without actually changing the copy.

Comment: @Kevin I think I have at least one massmarket/trade paperback duo with the same ISBN. My guess is, there's no ISBN police beyond using the right publisher number.

Comment: @Spencer: Yes, publishers can and do play fast and loose with the "new edition" rule, but if the books are materially different products (e.g. one has a new forward or something), then a consumer might feel ripped off if they don't get the one they wanted. So you can't just "reprint" your first-run hardcover edition as a mass-market paperback and hope nobody notices.